# TopShelf windows service memory leak while update information from sql

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service with prepared topshelf.This project send request web service and response xml data.After that this xml data serialize list objects and than these objects update information from sql.When Start service about 8 mb after that increase 1.8 gb memory out of range exception.Why ?

```
 public class HostService
{

    private readonly Timer _updaterThread;
    private readonly object _lockObject;
    private readonly Manager _manager;
    public HostService()
    {
        _manager = new Manager();
        _lockObject = new object();
        var interval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateInterval"]);
        _updaterThread = new Timer(interval) { AutoReset = true };
        _updaterThread.Elapsed += UpdateInfo;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            LoadLogger();
            _updaterThread.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FXEventLogger.Instance().AddLog(EventLogEntryType.Error, e);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateInfo(object state, EventArgs ev)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            _manager.UpdateFmdProductions();
        }
    }



    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {

            _updaterThread.Stop();
            FXEventLogger.Instance().AddLog(EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit, "Service stopped");
            FXEventLogger.Finalize();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FXEventLogger.Instance().AddLog(EventLogEntryType.Error, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please, show "UpdateFmdProductions();"

Comment: UpdateFmdProductions have two method calls that

Answer (score 0):

**UpdateFmdProductions() make two process First **
`public class SmdStatusProvider
    {

```
    public List<MakerInfo> GetMakersInfo()
    {
        SMDStatusServiceClient requester = null;
        try
        {
            requester = new SMDStatusServiceClient();

            var response = requester.Request("//MachineStatus[@MachineType='MAKER']/ShiftStatus");

            return ParseMakersInfo(response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FXEventLogger.Instance().AddLog(EventLogEntryType.Error, e);

            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            requester.Close();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }


    private List<MakerInfo> ParseMakersInfo(string shiftStatesXml)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(shiftStatesXml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MakerInfo>), new XmlRootAttribute("result"));

            var _makersInfo = (List<MakerInfo>) serializer.Deserialize(sr);

            sr.Dispose();

            return _makersInfo;
        }
    }
}`
```

public class FMDRepository : SqlServerClient
    {

```
    public FMDRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public bool UpdateRealProductions(IEnumerable<MakerInfo> makersInfo)
    {
        if (makersInfo == null) return false;

        OpenConnection();

        foreach (var makerInfo in makersInfo)
        {
            var success = ExecuteNonQuery(
                  String.Format("UPDATE [Shooter] SET [RealProduction]={0}, [LastUpdate]='{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' WHERE [Machine]='{2}'",
                      Math.Round(makerInfo.RealProduction, 0), DateTime.Now,
                      makerInfo.Machine));
            if (success == -1)
            {
                CloseConnection();
                return false;
            }
        }
        CloseConnection();
        return true;
    }
}
```